# How to read lexicon dictionary file .lex

Tags: java, file, dictionary, format

I am trying to implement an spellchecker in Java, but I have the dictionary as a ".lex" file as opposed to ".dic" file.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to read a ".lex" file?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know any more about what format these dictionary files are in? There are apparently several different applications that use the `.lex` file extension (Office, InDesign, COREX, etc).

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076874/learn-java/lexical-analysis-and-java--part-1.html did you check this out i have one more suggetion give exactly what you want to read and also a sample content of .lex file so we can work on it

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question in the current form because we don't know which actual `.lex` format do you use. Please post example file somewhere (if it is text, simply put it in code block in your question) so we can understand it's format.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. The .lex file is in binary format, thats my problem. :) Yes, Microsoft office can read .lex files, I am not sure what else can. I am able to import a .lex dictionary and use it as a spellchecker in Word. I am now just hoping someone who has already worked on something similar can help me..